# Live Drupal page editing

Tags: 7

Is there any module or a way for live editing Drupal's HTML Markup. I want to add few CSS classes to various fields.

Thanks

Comment: You want to edit nodes and other content, or themes? any reason traditional way is insufficient?

Comment: it will be alot more easier if there is such a way that you can directly edit your html live and the changes were saved with it. And what are the traditional way of doing it..?

Comment: traditional way is to edit node when you need to edit content, and to edit theme files if you need to edit site's design. Web pages are not like word documents keep on your local HDD, for example. Totally different architecture.

Comment: https://github.com/haystack/datapress-drupal/wiki/Editing-HTML-inside-Drupal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you want to add classes to fields, maybe this module will get that job done: https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class

You can find others as well, like block class module and I think there is one for menus or menu items (advanced menu module?), just search around.